# Error: The error occurred in row 1. Caused by error in `fisher.test()`: all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite in fisher.test

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I am running a Fisher Exact test on some contingency matrix in R. However, using the code on below data is producing an error:

Input data

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Ensembl_ID = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", 
"ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938", 
"ENSG00000000971"), sum_m = c(912.185436682647, -2328.62341333954, 
547.529608945287, 4.65090976012695, 908.403124275868, -1392.47602042934, 
-669.766831873008), length_m = c(602, 602, 602, 602, 602, 602, 
602), sum_w = c(542.094120582902, -1357.68164122714, 206.797589592733, 
58.9299572032901, 348.609667686873, -822.262487015913, -337.250829602427
), length_w = c(395, 395, 395, 395, 395, 395, 395)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5651d4218db0>)
```

Code which I am using for calculation of the row-wise fisher extract text.

```
f1 <- function(sum_m, sum_w, length_m, length_w) {
  x    <- c(sum_m, sum_w)
  n    <- c(length_m, length_w)
  mash <- rbind(c(sum_m, length_m - sum_m),
                c(sum_w, length_w - sum_w))
  
  fisher.test(mash)
}

df <- df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(out = list(f1(sum_m, sum_w, length_m, length_w) %>% 
                      broom::tidy(.)))  %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unnest(out)
```

Earlier it was working fine but now showing error

> Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `out = list(f1(sum_m, sum_w,   length_m, length_w) %>% broom::tidy(.))`. ℹ The error
> occurred in row 1. Caused by error in `fisher.test()`: ! all entries
> of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite Run `rlang::last_error()` to see
> where the error occurred. Called from: signal_abort(cnd, .file)

Thanks in advance for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

`fisher.test` expects a contingency table, but the matrix you feed this test, in function `f1`, does not look like such (check by inserting `print(mash)` in f1). Instead, it contains negative values which throws the error description `Caused by error in fisher.test(): ! all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite`.